# assign object to array

Tags: php

```
$var[1] = new Base();
$var[2] =& $var[1];
```

Will it make any difference to my script if I use `$var[2] = $var[1];` instead of `$var[2] =& $var[1];`

As it will eventually pass refrence to $var[2] when i write  `$var[2] = $var[1];`

Comment: any reason not doing this ? `$var[1] = $var[2] = new Base();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var[2] =& $var[1];
```

Will assign a reference of the second array element (not the value) to the third element:

```
class Base{};
$var[1] = new Base();
$var[2] =& $var[1];

$var[1] = 'foo';
var_dump($var);
```

prints

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  &string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  &string(3) "foo"
}
```

---

I think you only want both entries point to the same object and as objects are passed by reference, `$var[2] = $var[1];` is the correct way:

```
class Base{};
$var[1] = new Base();
$var[2] = $var[1];

$var[1]->foo = 'bar';
var_dump($var);
```

prints

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  object(Base)#1 (1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Base)#1 (1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
```

and if you do `$var[1] = 'foo'` afterwards it gives you:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  object(Base)#1 (1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can understand by an example

```
   $value1 = "Hello";
   $value2 =& $value1; /* $value1 and $value2 both equal "Hello". */
   $value2 = "Goodbye"; /* $value1 and $value2 both equal "Goodbye". */

   echo($value1);
   echo($value2);
```

let take another example

```
$a = array('a'=>'a');
$b = $a; // $b is a copy of $a
$c = & $a; // $c is a reference of $a
$b['a'] = 'b'; // $a not changed
echo $a['a'], "\n";
$c['a'] = 'c'; // $a changed
echo $a['a'], "\n";
```

output is a c

Comment: Thanks for reply. What you have explained is true for array and variable. But my question is for class and its object. how will it behave in case of object assignment.